# How to use python requests module as a website crawler?

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler

I want to build a web crawler totally from the requests module and don't want to use beautifulsoup or others.Is it possible to build one?

Comment: It only supports Python 3.6, what about Requests-HTML? [Requests-HTML: HTML Parsing for Humans (writing Python 3)!](http://requests-html.kennethreitz.org/)

Comment: requests module supports Python 3.8.But I will try your suggestion too.Thanks.